# How can I scale mono font to 90% of MatchLowercase

Tags: fontspec, fontsize

I would like to scale the mono font so that it's x-height is 90% of the x-height of the main font.  (I think it looks too large when the x-height matches.)  Is this possible?

Sample code with matching x-heights:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}[Scale=0.94]
\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

% Want 0.9 * MatchLowercase here:
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\newcommand\fox{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\begin{document}
\fox\par
\textsf{\fox}\par
\texttt{\fox}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: I’m not sure how `0.9 * MatchLowercase` can be achieved. But it is worth mentioning that `Source Serif/Sans Pro` seem to have very distinct cap height and ascender, while for `Latin Modern Mono` these two metrics are very close, e.g., the `Th` part. This could affect the visual appearance of the font size. IMO, using two `MatchLowercase`’s (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJT9c.png) produces sans too small. Using two `MatchUppercase`’s looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9fLF.png.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've gotten a good year of use of Ulrike's answer (thank you!), but there is now a better way. Or maybe it was always there and I never noticed it. In any case, this is a straight-forward way of doing it with fontspec's `ScaleAgain` facility:

```
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}[
  Scale       = MatchLowercase ,
  ScaleAgain  = 0.9 ,
  ]
```

Comment: Huh. I didn’t know about that, either. You saved me from writing code to find the x-height of both fonts and take the ratio.

Comment: Really a good catch...

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}[Scale=0.86] %=0.94*0.9
% Want 0.9 * MatchLowercase here:
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}[Scale=0.94]
\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\newcommand\fox{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}
\begin{document}
\fox\par
\textsf{\fox}\par
\texttt{\fox}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well that's clever.  Is there a way that the 0.94 can be saved in a "variable" somehow, so it's not effectively repeated?  This doesn't work:```\newcommand\myscale{0.94}
\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}[Scale=0.9\myscale]
 [...]
\setmainfont{Source Serif Pro}[Scale=\myscale]
```

Comment: `\usepackage{xfp}` and `Scale=\fpeval{\myscale*0.9}` should work.